# @types/react and @types/prop-types errors when building with gulp build or gulp serve

Tags: react, typescript, build

For my team's project, some of us are hitting a type issue when building.

We're using version `1.7.0` of all the `@microsoft/sp-` packages.

- tslint version: 5.9.1
- typescript version: 2.4.2
- Build tools version:3.8.33
- Node version:v8.14.1

Errors:

```
[09:16:53] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(31,38): error TS1005: '=' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(33,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(33,75): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(33,99): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,48): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,49): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,76): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,100): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,103): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,119): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,144): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,152): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(35,160): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(37,50): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(37,51): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(37,52): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(37,69): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(37,71): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(50,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(50,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(50,57): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(55,51): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(56,17): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(57,25): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,29): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,41): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,55): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,63): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(94,67): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(95,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(305,50): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(305,72): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(305,75): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(708,15): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(708,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(710,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(710,16): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(714,15): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(714,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(715,17): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(715,31): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(715,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(716,17): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(716,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(717,42): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(717,71): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(718,21): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(719,17): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(720,13): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(720,16): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(727,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(727,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(728,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(729,17): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(729,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(733,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(733,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(734,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(734,34): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(735,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(735,46): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2558,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2560,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2560,25): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2562,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2563,5): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2563,6): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2634,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2638,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2638,43): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2638,71): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2638,73): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2638,80): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2643,45): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,17): error TS1005: ']' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,18): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,19): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,35): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,38): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,40): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2644,48): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2645,13): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2645,21): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2645,27): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2646,11): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2647,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2647,12): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2648,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2648,12): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2649,39): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2649,40): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2655,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2656,14): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2656,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2657,9): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2658,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2659,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2660,5): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2660,12): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2662,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2662,66): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2662,89): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2663,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2664,5): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2664,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2664,36): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2664,37): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2666,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2666,13): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2666,43): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2666,44): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2668,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2668,16): error TS1005: ')' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2682,49): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2682,89): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2682,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2682,126): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2683,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2683,17): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2683,57): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2683,60): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2683,94): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2684,17): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2685,17): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2686,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - [tsc] node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2686,43): error TS1005: '(' expected.
Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 11 s
 exited with code 2
[09:16:54] Project my-web-parts version:0.0.1
[09:16:54] Build tools version:3.8.33
[09:16:54] Node version:v8.14.1
[09:16:54] Total duration:17 s
[09:16:54] Task errors:130
```

Is there a special way the project needs to be bootstrapped to have the types in the right format?

Comment: Most likely it's a version dependency issue. I recently encountered this with Mobx and had to install an older version. Post your package.json, and while you're waiting for responses, start backing out dependencies and try to isolate the exact package that's triggering this.